# Intersection of Multidimensional Gaussians

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have two multidimensional Gaussians (i.e. bell-curves or "bumps") for which I know the height, mean, and standard deviation (in each dimension) of each. I would like to represent their intersection by a third multi-dimensional Gaussian bump. (I realize this will be losing information, I just want to do the best I can in some sense.) How would I calculate the height, mean and standard deviation of this resulting Gaussian bump?